# Return a value taking into account both date and number

Tags: java, performance

I have 3 dates and 3 numbers

```
Date date1 = "2013-01-23";
Date date2 = "2013-03-24";
Date date3 = "2012-12-20";

number1 = 10;
number2 = 0;
number3 = 3;
```

Step 1: I have to check the latest date of the three I have and select the number corresponding to that date.

Step 2: If the number corresponding to that date is 0, I need next highest value among the three dates

**Note: The dates can be `null`**

My code works if all the dates are not null. I am confused to handle the case when one of the dates is `null`

```
if(date1 != null && date3 != null) {
   if(date1.compareTo(date3) > 0 && number1 > 0) {
     dateCompare = date1;
     object.set(number1);
   } else if(date3.compareTo(date1) > 0 && number3 > 0) {
       dateCompare = date3;
       object.set(number3);
   }
}

if(date2 != null) {
  if(dateCompare != null) {
     if(date2.compareTo(dateCompare) > 0 && number2 > 0 ) {
        object.set(number2);
        dateCompare = date2;
     }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Example if one of the dates is `null`
If `date1 = null` and `date2 > date3` . `number2  = 0` and `number3 = 1`. Then I want to set the value as `number3`

Can someone suggest me a way to handle what I am looking for ?

Comment: This is entirely application dependent.  What is the output you expect to see when one of your input values is null?

Comment: I suggest you create a flow chart with what output you want for what input, and then write the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you handle `null` is entriely up to you.

This example uses a `TreeMap` to sort your key/value pairs by `Date` and then loops in descending order until it finds a non-zero value.

This implementation drops `null` values as they cannot meaningfully be sorted. Judging from the OP's example this seems to be the right way to handle `null`. The only remaining question is what to do if everything is `null`.

```
private static final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final TreeMap<Date, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Date, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer put(Date key, Integer value) {
            if (key != null) {
                return super.put(key, value);                  
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    map.put(parseDate("2013-01-23"), 10);
    map.put(parseDate("2013-03-24"), 0);
    map.put(parseDate("2012-12-20"), 3);
    for (final Entry<Date, Integer> entry : map.descendingMap().entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() > 0) {
            System.out.println(entry + " has nonzero value");
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(entry + " has zero value. Continue looking.");
    }
}

public static Date parseDate(final String date) {
    if (date == null) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        return dateFormat.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Sun Mar 24 00:00:00 GMT 2013=0 has zero value. Continue looking.
Wed Jan 23 00:00:00 GMT 2013=10 has nonzero value
```

I would certainly suggest using the `TreeMap` rather than your custom code, it's clearer to other readers of your code. Any why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Please see the example in update. I am confused only when one or more dates are null. If everything is null I would set the number as `-`

Comment: I have overridden the `TreeMap` put method to ignore `null` - it doesn't get added to the `Map` - this will do what you want.